# LWC for scanning a QR code is not working in all mobile devices

Tags: lightning-web-components, mobile, qr-code

I am using a lwc to scan a QR code that's working all right . However the problem  is that it's not working in all devices . Actually , the camera that will scan the code is opened but it can't detect the Qr code .

I tried the same code in different devices and it worked in some and didn't in others . So the Pb isn't in the lwc . Does anyone have any ideas ????

Comment: This is going to be very difficult to help you with unless you can provide some of your LWC code, a working example, and some specifics about the particular QR code you're testing, which devices work and which ones do not etc.

Comment: @MarkPond Here is the code I am using : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_barcodescanner_example

Answer (score 2):

From the Salesforce BarcodeScanner [Considerations and Limitations documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_barcodescanner_considerations):

***Device Limitations***

BarcodeScanner doesn’t implement scanning itself. Instead, it makes available the scanning feature of the underlying platform (Android or iOS). While the features provided by BarcodeScanner are the same across both platforms, it is subject to some platform-specific quirks and minor differences.

BarcodeScanner requires the use of the mobile device camera. The user must grant your app access to the camera. The exact user experience is governed by the platform. The request happens automatically on first use, and is managed by the device itself, but you should plan for it when designing the user experience of your app.
BarcodeScanner automatically uses the “main” camera. There’s no way to select a different camera on devices that have more than one.
If you can’t get a clear picture of the barcode, it can’t be recognized. The quality of the device camera affects barcode recognition. A damaged or low-quality camera lens or focusing system, poor lighting, motion, and other factors can make it difficult or impossible to get a clear picture of a barcode.
The quality of the barcode affects barcode recognition. Specifically, damaged or obscured barcodes are hard to recognize successfully.
If you’re having trouble getting BarcodeScanner to recognize a barcode, try the following:

First, verify that the barcode type is one of the supported barcode symbologies. There are other barcode types that aren’t supported.
Second, verify that you’ve configured BarcodeScanner to recognize the expected symbology. See BarcodeScannerOptions in BarcodeScanner Data Types for configuration details.
Finally, check whether another app on the same device is able to recognize the barcode. If the standard camera app on the device can’t recognize the barcode, neither can BarcodeScanner.

Please go through this if something was missing.

Comment: Thank you for your respone . Actually ,the standard camera app of the device can easily recognize the barcode when I am using an other app . But, When I use it in the app of Salesforce , it's not working !!! So I don't think that it's related to the quality of the device nor the other factors . PS : HERE IS the code I am using :https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_barcodescanner_example